# Split API into micro-services

Tags: php, web-services, api, symfony

I've have one question about architecture.

We have api for mobile backed. And now we implementing some new features, like **user messaging**. 
For no api uses one database, and I want to have separate api and database for messages. Like micro-services. api.somedomain.com, messages.somedomain.com, etc.

Main api is guarded by implementing access via access keys. And in micro-services databases I need some data from main database, like user info, profile info, etc.

Maybe someone have ideas how to implement such mechanism?

Maybe master-slave replication with slave = database where I need information from main database?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can just create some endpoints in your main API to get the information your want. In your new micro services you can consume this API. I think it's a beautiful design and make you application more agnostic and extensible

Perhaps mapping each database involved as an separated entity manager.

You can map the new services as new container services and new controllers.
Symfony and Doctrine allows you to access different entity managers very easily.

Replication is a good resource, but sometimes it's cumbersome. Maintaining a replica set requires additional efforts and hardware.

You should evaluate if  the database is too big or might have some performance issue due the micro services consuming the main database.

Comment: If I've have one big application(api) working with 2 databases would be very easy. But I need few applications with separated databases, and some of data need to be in all databases, like user and access keys.

Comment: In this case replication could be a nice choice, if you can't access the main database. Be aware that the changes you make in the slave will not be replied into the master.

Comment: Replication was just thoughts, because I don't know how to do in this case

Comment: I had an application backed by a master-master replica. I have to say, it's not that easy to maintain a thing like that.

Comment: Maybe you can just create some endpoints in your main API the get the information your want.  In your new micro services you can consume this API. I think it's a beautiful design and make you application more agnostic and extensible...

Comment: Just put my last comment directly in the answer.

Comment: We decided to use bundles as endpoints with few databases and it will be one codebase appication

Comment: Sounds good, @Cawa. What do you use for your API FosRestBundle?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102505/discussion-between-cawa-and-omar-alves).